# Copy Library Permissions of Group Tibco Spotfire

Tags: command-line, permissions, config, spotfire, tibco

I'm trying to copy the library permissions from one group to another in Spotfire 7.6.0 using the congig.bat command line program. These are the commands I'm running:

```
> cd c:\Tibco\tss\7.6.0\tomcat\bin  
> config.bat copy-library-permissions -g "Automation Services Users" -p "Scheduled Updates Users"
```

I get the error:

```
The group 'Automation Services Users' does not exist
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it not supported to copy permissions of system groups? I can accomplish this manually but I want to automate for deployment across our installations.